# Jquery Mobile on Android - trouble with Cyrillic auto-complete

Tags: android, autocomplete, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to perform autocomplete with Cyrillic and English data.

If I type some search text in English everything is fine (except overall speed of jQuery  on Android), but when I try to search for something in Russian or Ukrainian the phone sticks.

Comment: Are you sure you are using jQuery Mobile Framework? Or just jquery in a mobile application? I'm asking just to be sure

Comment: i'm using JQUERY MOBILE 1.0 ALPHA 3

Answer (score 0):

How does a phone stick?

Ok, seriously - See if this has to do with encoding. Maybe at some stage you didn't define encoding as utf-8. Be sure to do it in HTML head and on the server side.

[edit]

The problem seems to be with keypress event.

After you preform tests I suggested (running on desktop webkit and checking if keypress is triggered at all in android) report back and I will be able to help and fill in this answer

Comment: i mean that i don't get any response neither in real Android devices nor in Android emulator. encoding is set to utf-8 on both sides.

Comment: I can help you more if you publish an example somewhere. I'm from Poland, so I'll be able to generate some funny characters too.

Comment: To tell the truth I'm not able to press anything on Russian keyboard on any device running under Android, even when I've created a single page with a mobile framework and a single text input. Browser don't understand keypress event, but English works fine.

Comment: Test it on desktop in any webkit browser to see if it's JQM's fault or just Android not passing keypresses to browser.

Comment: Android passes keypresses to browser when English keyboard is activated, but when i try to do it with Russian keyboard, I get autocomplete results pressing spacebar after search query, but nothing happens dynamically...

Comment: I see 2 posibilities: 1. No keypress event is triggered in javascript for cyrylic characters OR 2. the event handler tests if e.charCode is a proper one. For the first one - there's nothing you can do. For the second one - change the keypress event handler code so that it doesn't have any restrictions on e.charCode

Comment: As i see there is only one possibility : "No keypress event is triggered in javascript for cyrylic characters". Even google in Android browser don't suggest anything in auto-complete when you try to search using cyrillic letters.

Comment: This just means that google has a similiar implementation of suggestions. Why don't you try and bind to keypress a simple function that alerts `event.keyCode`? If event fires and is then ignored by autocomplete due to a weird keycode, then it can be fixed